# i don't known what does the symbol,"#" mean in the following src of the nutch's HttpBase.java

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

When I come to the following src of the nutch's `HttpBase.java`, I don't known what does the symbol,"#" mean in the author's desription:

```
// get # of threads already accessing this addr
Integer counter = (Integer)THREADS_PER_HOST_COUNT.get(host);
```

Comment: this really isn't programming related - should be on english.stackexchange.com but # is a common abbreviation for "number"

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking questions in any forum.

Comment: i'm sorry but i have already do some research before asking.but,anyway,thank u for ur suggetstion

Answer (score 12):

It's just shorthand for "number" or "count". So "Find out the # of users we need to support" would be shorthand for "Find out the number of users we need to support" in the same way.

See the wikipedia page for ["number sign"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) for more information.